# OSGI Container for raspberry pi 3 using GE Predix

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

May I know how to create OSGI container for raspberry pi using GE Predix, can you please give the reply as soon as possible.

Thanks & Regards,
Eswara G

Comment: Edit your question with what you done so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [Add Predix Machine on an Edge Device](https://www.predix.io/resources/tutorials/tutorial-details.html?tutorial_id=1742&tag=Edge&journey=Edge) tutorial.  It has instructions for quickly loading Predix Machine (built using the OSGi framework) for both an Intel Edison and Raspberry Pi.  There shouldn't be a need to create an OSGi container from scratch, [Predix Machine](https://www.predix.io/docs/?r=155620#mL2j0aax) **is** the OSGi container you are probably looking for.

Hope that helps get you going.